# Mouse X/Y detection within Flash stage not working Moz & Webkit on PC

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I am trying in vain to get this Flash based navigational item working in FF and Chrome on PC.  It's all good on Mac and it's just fine using IE 7 or 8 on PC.

The nav item consists of a ball that "follows" the cursor in relation to where it is on the page.  JS is used to gather the X/Y info from off the Flash stage and create vars to be used by the Flash movie to move the "orb" in relation to the cursor position.  For some reason, FF and Chrome on PC fall short here.

I've tried everything from setting the Flash movie to "opaque" and positioning a transparent DIV over it, all to no avail.

Any thoughts on this?  Has anyone encountered something like this?

Example here:

http://anthrograph.com/yarbyarb/thang/

We were given the compiled SWF with the listeners setup, but as of now, I do not have access to the FLA to make changes.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason the swf itself isn't set up with its own mouse listeners / position detection?  If not, is there a reason you can't have the source code to add that functionality?

Comment: scriptocalypse,  I would think that the original author did in fact set up the Flash movie to have its own listeners.  I am admittedly a Flash moron but I realize that you probably have a debug environment to see what's being tracked/listened to by the file.  Do you in fact notice that there are no internal listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried in chrome and firefox, when mouse is on html part, positioning is working, while mouse is on flash it is not working.

if i understand, easiest solution is for window mode, you should make a displayObject, a sprite and set it to belove everything else with alpha = 0, with this you can set window mode anything you like.

other then, you should add Listener to MouseLeave and MouseMove to detect when listen javascript or actionscript.

there is another error, you should mask your buttons that right side. they are under other graphic but mouse_over is working when it should not. For this use ROLL_OVER instead of MOUSE_OVER.

Comment: Viaria,  you are surely on the right track. I had original developer implement your suggestions and all is working well -- UNTIL you go off the stage and RETURN to the stage at which point the mouse tracking no longer works.  The developer theorizes that this may be because JS has now set some values that FLASH is using and they need to become undefined or something when you return to the movie.  I will work on this and when done ,post solution and give you the check mark.  THANKS

Comment: Giving you the Green Check as your advice totally led me in the right direction.  Be sure when topping this off to set an area for the movie with a block level element and assign an "onmousemove" event that nulls out the variables being passed back to the Flash movie by JS.  Oh yeah, and set that wmode to OPAQUE.